# Top 3 Customers in terms of total amount purchased in each month with rank in each month

Tags: postgresql

I want to trying to find Top 3 Customers name in terms of total amount purchased in each month with rank in each month

from 3 table 1 table

```
Product

Product_id  product_name product_price
P1           ABC           20
P2           DEF           30
```

2nd Table

```
Sales

Cust_id     Date     Quantity    Product_id
C1         1-Jan-21     3           P1
C1         2-Feb-21     4           P2
C2         5-Jan-21     6           P1
C2         7-Jan-21     1           P1
C3         9-feb-21     5           P2
```

thrid table

```
Customer

ID     Name
C1     JKL
C2     MNO
C3     OPQ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First calculate the monthly purchase amounts of customers (CTE t)
then rank the monthly amounts (CTE r)
and finally filter by rank and order.

```sql
with t as 
(
 select 
    s.cust_id,
    date_trunc('month', "Date") as period,
    s.quantity * p.product_price as amount 
 from sales s join product p on s.product_id = p.product_id
 group by period, s.cust_id
), 
r as
(
 select *,
    row_number() over (partition by period order by amount desc) as rank
 from t
)
select r.period, c.name as cust_name, r.rank as period_rank
from r join customer c on r.cust_id = c.id
where rank <= 3 
order by r.period, r.rank;
```

This query can be written less verbose but I think that clarity and readability will suffer.